# "Languages" not found in Admin/Configuration

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 7.41 in a remote server linux configuration

Installed and Enabled

1. [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)
2. Locale
3. [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable)
4. [Entity Traslation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation)
5. Content Translation

Next, want to Add the Spanish and French languages. But, there is no Languages option seen under "Regional and language" in Admin/Configuration.

What is missing?
Tried flushing all caches. No difference.
Logged in as admin user/1

Comment: I never saw something like this, try access to YOUR_SITE/admin/config/regional/language let me know the result.

Comment: Tried this - it showed "You are not authorized to access this page." Don't remember seeing any access related steps in all the multilingual setup docs.

Comment: you are logged with the admin account?

Comment: Please EDIT your question to indicate if you are yes or no using "user/1" in your scenario ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a permission named ***Administer languages***, I make some test with it and I can reproduce your issue. Go to `YOUR_SITE/admin/people/permissions` and search under the ***Locale*** section the ***Administer languages*** permission and give the permission to your user.

[image]

Comment: Curiosity: if you were able to reproduce this "bizarre" issue, I'd assume that you did so with a userid different from user/1, right? Because user/1 ALWAYS has access to anything (which I'm sure you know). Maybe you want to enhance your answer to clarify that ...?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you are correct this is the reason for I make the question about the user to the OP

Comment: Well, depends what you call "admin account" ... If (eg) user/3 has been granted role "administrator" also ... Would you call that an admin account or not? IMHO that's different: in that case user/3 has access to anything granted to role "administrator". While for user/1 there is no need to "grant" those same permissions (user/1 ALWAYS has all permissions, and is "considered God in Drupal". So that's why I think you've to be careful and differentiate, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you're right, In the case of user/1 this is not the solution. I have installed the same modules of the OP and I see the link, I don't know the solution. But my answer can help other users. Do you think that I should delete my answer?

Comment: **NO**, don't delete it, just enhance it a bit further to "share what you learned" via my small "hey wait a minute"-intervention here. No need for credits or mentioning my name or so, because YOU did the effort to double check the challenge I posted in these comments. And I'm happy knowing that "you" learned something from it, n'est pas? After you're done please notify me via an extra comment (so that I can QA-read it and remove my comments around here). ça va? PS: afterwards I might post another answer (if I know one ... what do you think?)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks I short of time at this moment because I need to go to my class, can you improve the answer please?

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. 

I was thinking that this should be mentioned in some of those Mulitilingual setup guides/help docs. For whatever reason, the permission step got skipped/missed during the installation process. It might happen with others.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens we don't know why, but the OP says that this works ;-)

Comment: @user3652449 a pleasure, when I have the time I will go to edit the documentation ;-)